# PDF programatically set font without being forced to set font size

Tags: pdf

According to the PDF syntax given by Adobe [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) it seems that there is no possibility to set the actual font, without setting at the same time also the font size.

I am in the situation that the font size is already specified and set before together with a different font. I just want to keep the size just alter the font.

Exemplarily looks like this

```
/F1 12 Tf
```

where F1 "reprents" the font, the font size being 12.

Did I miss something, or is there a nice workaround for it?
Please note, that I have no access to the current font size and don't want to alter it.

Comment: This is understood, but the font and the font size are representing text state.
If this state is already set before, I would like to keep parts of the state.
In my particular case I would like to keep the font size, just alter the font.

Comment: You may be right that my question is misleading, so I corrected it a bit

Comment: *"Did I miss something, or is there a nice workaround for it?"* - You didn't miss anything, there is no work-around, when creating new or manipulating existing pdf content, you are expected to supply font size and font name together.  (The comments here look incomplete, so maybe this already had been said before.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally it requires a PDF editor to do font replacement, often with mixed results, as there is no simple means to substitute one font tag for another here I crafted a PDF to show how just simply swapping /F1 /F2 /F3 and /F4 may corrupt the output.

So line 1 and 2 are different styles of Arial font and lines 3 and 4 are Consolas so we can see as I cycle the font tags I might be able to replace one style by another but here only once in each font family and clearly line length will be changed.

[image]

So IF you know you want to swap style later it is essential to use proportional / fixed pitch static fonts.

[image]

IF you plan ahead it is possible to embed fonts for swapping style but generally not family, OR you could as many do set a generic font and rely on the system replacing those with local default fonts.

Otherwise you need to read the text in one font and rewrite that text block in a different font bearing in mind the need to reflow the line lengths or adjust sizes to suit, hence many a font is found with non uniform units.

For fairly simple font substitution I would normally resort to X-change editor or FlexiPDF editor